# isomorphic react.js without flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reactjs-flux, isomorphic-javascript

I am newbie with react.js . I want to make isomorphic react.js component . I wonder is it possible to make it without flux pattern ? Now I have little component and there is api fetch method inside component and as it seems this api call runs twice :( .

For more clarity, I want to render DOM in server side , and want to handle react.js component events in browser side .

My component looks like :

```
Class MyComponent extends React.Component{

 // my component code 
 // components events 

 render() {} 

}


if (!is_server()) {


apiFetch.my_api_call(function (result) {
    ReactDom.render(<MyComponent data={result.data}/>, document.getElementById('navigation'))
});


}else{

apiFetch.my_api_call(function (result) {
    res.status(200).send(
        ReactDOMServer.renderToString(React.createElement(MyComponent, {data: result.data}))
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a parent Component whose child will be `MyComponent`

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // make api call
    apiCall.then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        reqData : data,
      })
    })
  }

  getComponentToRender() {
    if(typeof this.state.reqData === 'undefined') {
      return false;
    } else {
      return (
        <MyComponent data={result.data}/>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    const componentToRender = this.getComponentToRender();
    return (
      <div>
        <componentToRender />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now, render your ParentComponent irrespective of the api call. Once, the `ParentComponent` is mounted, it will automatically trigger the rendering of `MyComponent`.